# Phabricator arcanist not working

Tags: phabricator

I have installed `phabricator` and `arcanist`. But still having issues.

When I run `arc` command it gives me this error:

```
"/bin/env: php: No such file or directory"
```

I have updated environment variable. But can;t figure out problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be complaining about trying to find PHP.  Do you have PHP installed and in your environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/env` looks for the argument, `php`, in your `PATH` and calls it, the error states that `/bin/env` cannot find the binary of `php` in your `PATH`. `arc` is a php script and uses `/bin/env` to find your php binary.

If you type `echo $PATH` - ensure that the php binary is located in one of those directories.

Comment: Do you need WAMP or XAMPP to Run Phabricator on Windows or can I configure the PATH in Phabricator?